# Best way to change data on FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, firebase-realtime-database

currently I am using **FirebaseRecyclerAdapter** to represent data on a RecyclerView using the following Firebase query:

```
postsQuery = mDatabase.child("lists_new”).orderByKey().limitToFirst(10);
```

My RecyclerView has a header with 2 buttons: **New List, Old List**.
New list is loaded by default, and my question is,  when the user taps the Old List button, what is the ***most efficient way to replace the new list with old list***.

The Firebase query for the old list looks like this:

```
postsQuery = mDatabase.child("lists_old”).orderByKey().limitToFirst(10);
```

Note: *both new list and the old list has the same data types, i.e. they share the same Java POJO class and the the same layout.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a similar need and a similar solution except I am calling cleanup() on the adapter before new'ing up another one. I am thinking without calling cleanup() it will create a leak of adapters and/or listeners?

In onActivityCreated() in my Fragment I am calling a method in the Fragment that manages the recycler view. Call the method to initialize or refresh the list and pass in a leaf node name. If the adapter is not null then call cleanup(). Create a new database reference by concatenating a new leaf node with the parent reference, new-up a new adapter and set it.

I call cleanup() in onDestroy() as well, per usual.

It works fine so far though I've only tested using the emulator and a small data set.

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    refreshList(newLeafNode);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mRVAdapter.cleanup();
}

protected void refreshList(String newLeafNode) {

    if (mRVAdapter != null) {
        mRVAdapter.cleanup();
    }

    DatabaseReference newDbRef = mParentRef.child(newLeafNode);

    mRVAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<String, MyViewHolder>(String.class, R.layout.single_row, MyViewHolder.class, newDbRef) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(MyViewHolder viewHolder, String model, int position) {
            viewHolder.setImage(model);
        }
    };
    mMyRV.setAdapter(mRVAdapter);
}
```

Comment: Awesome, I think you are right, calling cleanup() is necessary to avoid leaks to real-time database listeners. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 3):

You will need a new adapter and attach that to the same RecyclerView.

So after constructing the new query, you create a new adapter and attach it to the view:

```
adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Chat, ChatHolder>(
   Chat.class, android.R.layout.two_line_list_item, ChatHolder.class, postsQuery) {
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Yes, I am currently doing it this way, but is this really the most efficient way to do this? Just curious, Thanks so much for the quick reply though.

Comment: I don't know of a more efficient approach. I also have no reason to think it is inefficient. If you have other experience, share details please.

Comment: It's just that I saw a changeQuery(Query ref); method in FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.

Comment: You must be looking at another adapter then: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/database/FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java

Comment: Yap you are right, my adapter is an extended adapter of the default one, sorry for the confusion. Anyway thanks so much for the help.